# jQuery serialize value to PHP

Tags: jquery, serialization, kohana

I am a beginner in integrating jQuery and PHP. I tried using the nestedsortable plugin of jquery and successfully integrated it to my kohana 2.3.4 framework. My problem is how can I pass the serialize array value of jquery to php? Here is a snippet of my code.

In my View:

```
<ol class="sortable">
    <li id="list_1"><div>Item 1</div>
    <li id="list_2"><div>Item 2</div>
        <ol>
            <li id="list_3"><div>Sub Item 1.1</div>
            <li id="list_4"><div>Sub Item 1.2</div>
            <li id="list_5"><div>Sub Item 1.3</div>
            <li id="list_6"><div>Sub Item 1.4</div>
        </ol>
</ol>

<script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
        disableNesting: 'no-nest',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        handle: 'div',
        helper: 'clone',
        items: 'li',
        opacity: .6,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        tabSize: 25,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        toleranceElement: '> div'
    });

    $('#serialize').click(function(){
        serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');
        $('#serializeOutput').text(serialized);
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you actually starting a new project using Kohana v2.3?

Answer (score 2):

Via an AJAX Call:
"serialized" = your serialized data.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "myPhpScript.php",
   data: serialized
 });
```

More on this [in the jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

In your PHP file, you can access these variables through $_POST.

```
$myVar = $_POST['myVar'];
```

I don't know exactly how your serialized variables are called, but you can always "var_dump($_POST)" to see the contents of the POST data, and figure it out from there.

Comment: Thanks Nik for a very quick reply. My question is how can fetch it in php?? I am using kohana 2.3.4 framework

Comment: Use `Arr::get($_POST, 'myVar')` to avoid of access to variable that doesnt exist.

Comment: THanks again. ajax is not working.. what part of the script shall I put it?

Comment: Michael, it's a different issue if your AJAX is not working for whatever reason. Suggest you ask a new question or better yet search and see if it might have been answered before. Remember to show your entire code too.

Answer (score 0):

Stick all of this into your $(document).ready(function()/

```
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    disableNesting: 'no-nest',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    maxLevels: 10,
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div'
});

$('#serialize').click(function(){
        serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');
        $('#serializeOutput').text(serialized+'\n\n');
        $.post({
                type: "POST",
                url: "script.php",
                data: serialized
    });
})
```

Assuming that you have your serialize button handy, simply click the button and the data will be posted.  Notice that I just added .post instead of .ajax.  From my tests (I am using Django, not php), both .post and .ajax work fine.